# Django send password reset link via email when new user account added

Tags: django, django-users

I am working on an application where admins will create new user accounts. A randomized password is auto-generated when the user is added. Ideally an email will be automatically sent to the new user with a link to reset their password (It will not include the autogenerated password). I could figure out how to send an email with link to a page to enter an email to get a password reset link. However, I would like to avoid the extra steps and simply send the link to reset the password.

Any suggestions about how to trigger and send this link?

The model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
from django.contrib import admin
from django.db.models import Count
from django.db.models.signals import post_save


class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
    age = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    employee_type = models.ForeignKey(Group, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, default=1)
    employee_start_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(null=False, default=True)
```

The view:

```
class AddCompanyEmployee(CreateView):
    model = CustomUser
    template_name = 'manage/add_employee.html'
    form_class = BrowserCreateUserForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('directory')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        password = CustomUser.objects.make_random_password()
        account = form.save(commit=False)
        account.password = make_password(password)
        account.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

The form:

```
class BrowserCreateUserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ['username','full_name', 'email', 'employee_type', 'employee_start_date', 'is_active']

        widgets = {
            'employee_start_date': forms.DateInput(attrs=dict(type='date')),
        }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
          Div('username', css_class='form-group col-lg-6'),
          Div('full_name', css_class='form-group col-lg-6'),
          Div('email', css_class='form-group col-lg-6'),
          Div('employee_type', css_class='form-group col-lg-3'),
          Div('employee_start_date', css_class='form-group col-lg-3'),
          Div('is_active', css_class='form-group col-lg-3'),

            )
        self.helper.add_input(Submit('submit', 'Submit'))
```

Comment: Why does a password need to be created? Just restrict the registration view to people who have been invited?

Comment: That could be one way to handle it. In this case it seems to make sense that the account owner will add the users (employees in this case) and the details associated with the account. However your suggestion is one way to handle it. A placeholder password is already generated. I only need to figure out how to automatically send a link to the new user to reset their password.